# Carousel responsive settings error in the console log

Tags: jquery, html, razor, carousel, slick.js

i have some **jcarousel** in my page with same `responsive` setting and all other settings are the same, but for one of them i get console error but it works fine for other carousels :

> Invalid slick slider responsive breakpoints setting value!

```
        var responsiveBreakpointsObj = {};
        var carouselHtmlElementId = "@carousel.Settings.CarouselHtmlElementId";
        var jCarousel = $("#" + carouselHtmlElementId + " .slick-carousel"); // Each carousel has different id
 try {

       responsiveBreakpointsObj = JSON.parse('[{"breakpoint":1680,"settings":{"slidesToShow":7}},{"breakpoint":1420,"settings":{"slidesToShow":6}},{"breakpoint":1200,"settings":{"slidesToShow":5}},{"breakpoint":869,"settings":{"slidesToShow":4}},{"breakpoint":616,"settings":{"slidesToShow":3}},{"breakpoint":443,"settings":{"slidesToShow":2}}]');

       for (var i = 0; i < responsiveBreakpointsObj.length; i++) {
               if (responsiveBreakpointsObj[i].settings.slidesToShow < numOfSlidesToScroll) {
                   responsiveBreakpointsObj[i].settings.slidesToScroll = responsiveBreakpointsObj[i].settings.slidesToShow;
               }
           }          
     }
 catch (e) {
             console.log('Invalid slick slider responsive breakpoints setting value!');
           }
jCarousel.slick({      // calling carousel slick
                infinite: true,
                slidesToShow: 8,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                autoplay: false,
                appendArrows: '.carousel-title',
                cssEase: 'linear',
                respondTo: 'slider',
                edgeFriction: 0.05,
                initialSlide: 0,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: false,
                responsive: responsiveBreakpointsObj
            });
```

It's a bit strange if this `responsiveBreakpointsObj` has any issue **why i get only one error** in the console log for that specific carousel?

**My second question is if this breakpoints setting is invalid why it works fine on every responsive break points?!**

Any suggest would be appreciated. :)

Comment: in catch section, can you add console.log(e) and post what is the output of that?

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic i get `invalid responsive setting value line x` in the console log.

Comment: Can you try to start from only one json breakpoint and see if it will break? Something like this: responsiveBreakpointsObj = JSON.parse('[{"breakpoint":1680,"settings":{"slidesToShow":7}}');

Comment: @NemanjaTodorovic thank you so much for helping , sure i will do it , but it's our live website so i can do it right now. i will try it as soon as i could and will update question :)

Comment: i tried this and i stil get `responsiveBreakpointsObj = JSON.parse('{"breakpoint":443,"settings":{"slidesToShow":2}}]');` invalid

Comment: you can see console log yourself if you can : https://hilandbeauty.com/fa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the code from your site and the problem is that variable `numOfSlidesToScroll` is undefined. Your parsing of json is actually ok :)

This is the section of code that throws exception for you:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < responsiveBreakpointsObj.length; i++) {
               if (responsiveBreakpointsObj[i].settings.slidesToShow < numOfSlidesToScroll) {
                   responsiveBreakpointsObj[i].settings.slidesToScroll = responsiveBreakpointsObj[i].settings.slidesToShow;
               }
           }
```

Comment: oh yesss it seems someshow i forgot to declare it .. thank you :)

Comment: it solved by adding  `var numOfSlidesToScroll = 1`; thank you :)